# Gostaria de saber como funciona o Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Vi vários tutoriais na internet, e vários matérias no youtube, mas até agora não entendi o funcionamento.

Na maioria das coisas que eu vi, ensinava a instalar uma maquina virtual e rodar, mas depois dai, eu faço o que? Como isso pode me ajudar em um projeto futuro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A principal vantagem do Vagrant no meu entender é permitir que cada desenvolvedor utilize os recursos nativos do seu ambiente durante o desenvolvimento (ex.: editor de texto, IDE, etc) porém o **ambiente de execução** (*runtime*) seja idêntico para todos eles - e este idêntico (na medida do possível) àquele que será usado em produção.

O primeiro passo, como você já percebeu, é instalar e executar uma máquina virtual. Mas qual? Ora, aquela que for mais parecida com o ambiente no qual o sistema executará de fato. Se for uma arquitetura cliente-servidor, a máquina virtual deve usar o mesmo sistema operacional do servidor, ter instalados na mesma os mesmos pacotes que estarão presentes no servidor (e na mesma versão), etc. Se for um sistema multi-plataforma, que precisa executar em diversos ambientes distintos, então você criaria uma máquina virtual distinta para cada um deles (sem precisar manter todas em operação ao mesmo tempo, é claro).

Uma vez definido a(s) máquina(s) virtual(s) a se utilizar, e como será feita sua configuração (é possível pré-instalar um conjunto de dependências, ou criar um script de inicialização para cada máquina virtual a ser executado durante sua criação), esta deve ser disponibilizada a cada desenvolvedor da sua equipe, de modo que todos trabalhem em um ambiente idêntico.

O último passo é mapear um conjunto de pastas do ambiente hospedeiro (i.e. seu computador) a um conjunto de pastas do ambiente hóspede (i.e. a máquina virtual). Isso permite que você edite arquivos, faça modelagens, etc usando suas ferramentas preferidas (que podem ser diferentes daquelas dos seus colegas), mas na hora de compilar e executar tudo seja feito dentro do ambiente virtual. Assim, ao executar, as diferenças entre computadores tenham seu impacto minimizado, se restringindo somente à performance (i.e. a capacidade do sistema hospedeiro de emular o sistema hóspede).

Nada impede que você compile/execute *também* no seu próprio computador, é claro, se o mesmo oferecer um ambiente compatível. O importante é você nunca disponibilizar ("fazer o *check-in*") arquivos que foram testados somente na sua máquina. Em vez disso, antes de colocar suas modificações no controle de versões você deve abrir cada máquina virtual (se houver só uma, melhor deixar aberto direto) e testar o sistema nela, de modo a garantir que o que funciona em um ambiente não cause bugs em outro.

Comment: Obrigado pelas as explicações. Mas o ponto principal é ai... isso eu já sabia, até então. Eu quero realmente entender como posso usar isso, pq até agora vi sendo usado em command line, ou seja, não vi uma vantagem, exemplos: **nodejs** **npm** **bower** deixe esses exemplos pq eu vejo uma "utilização" neles, mas até agora o que eu entendi do **Vagrant** é, baixar, instalar, e iniciar, mas pra que?, e como usar?, como me servir?, não entendi bem a logica dele até agora

Comment: @vinibudd Por favor edite sua pergunta então especificando exatamente o que quer saber. Da forma como está agora, me pareceu que sua dúvida era quanto ao **propósito** do Vagrant (o que creio que minha resposta já explicou de forma resumida).

Answer (score 1):

O Vagrant cria um ambiente virtual que isola as dependências e configurações em um único ambiente. Uma vez que alguém tenha criado um vagrantfile, basta que você execute o comando **vagrant up** que tudo é configurado e instalado para você.

Você também pode utilizar o vagrant para testar uma app em alguma nuvem remota, com exatamente a mesma configuração da sua máquina.

Answer (score 1):

O Vagrant te ajuda a ter um ambiente de desenvolvimento mais próximo ao de produção. E se - por exemplo - um funcionário entrar na sua empresa, basta pegar essa **box** *(imagem do sistema, já configurada para cada gosto e necessidade)* com as configurações necessárias para ele. O custo/tempo para se replicar esse ambiente e os testes para a sua aplicação são melhores.

Se você estiver utilizando o Windows, você irá se conectar com a sua máquina virtual via SSH. [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) irá te ajudar nisso.

Recomendo, também, a leitura de [Usando o Vagrant como ambiente de desenvolvimento no Windows](http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-o-vagrant-como-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-no-windows)